# saving time range

Tags: database

hi what is the best datatype in mssql to save time range? e.g. 1PM - 1.45PM 
Could i save this in only 1 column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save them in two separate `DateTime` columns, so you can run calculations on them later on.